# Mac Terminal and Vim syntax coloring on CentOS server

Tags: vi

I am using a Mac Terminal window to ssh to a CentOS server.  I have installed vim-enhanced on the server, I have created an alias for `vi=vim` in my `.bash_profile`, as well as confirmed I am using `/usr/bin/vim`. I still can't get syntax colors when editing files.

Is there something I need to do with Mac Terminal settings? Any thoughts as to why it's not working as I expect?

Answer (score 1):

Display ANSI colors needs to be enabled in the Terminal Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the line `syntax on` somewhere in the file `~/.vimrc` (on the host machine)?
That should do it.